# Double Complex with exact co-boundary operator on forms with compact support

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

I am reading Bott and Tu.

https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/botttu.pdf

On page 140 of that book, the exactness of co-boundary operator $\delta$ is used to prove that the double complex of forms with compact support has only one non zero column. "By the exactness of the rows, $H_{\delta}(K)$ is:" and then we are shown a figure with all but column zero filled with zeros. The zero column is $\Omega_c^i$ where $i=0, 1..$

When I look at the exactness and the definition of  $H_{\delta}(k)$, I conclude that all columns have to be zero including the zero column. After all exactness means kernel=image and thus the cohomology should all be zero. What am I missing? Why is there a non-zero column at all?

ps: The answers in comments below have confused me even more :), so if anyone can give a comprehensive answer, I shall be grateful.

Comment: Clearly the row complexes are exact save in dimension zero, where the cohomology (just the cokernel of the final map) is the desired group $\Omega_c^i(M)$. I.e., the rows are *resolutions* of the $\Omega_c^i(M)$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown  but the kernel of the sum operator going to $\Omega_c^*(M)$ on the page 139 prop 12.12 is the image of the delta operator from previous step. ie. the cohomology is trivial. Take the very simple case of  just two intersecting open sets, then the kernel of the sum are those forms which are zero outside the intersection and have opposite signs on the intersection which is exactly those forms which are in the image of delta. Delta is the extension by zero of the intersection with opposite signs on the intersection for the two sets. see the def. on page 139.

Comment: These are spaces of forms with compact support: for $U\subset V$ there is a map $\Omega_c^*(U)\to\Omega_c^*(V)$, not in the other dimension (so we are dealing with cokernels not kernels).

Comment: But on page 139, proof of exactness, it is shown that whenever $\delta w=0$ then $w$ is the image of the previous step. ie kernel/image is being argued as defining  the cohomology. Also nowhere in the book so far we have defined the $\delta$ operator any other way. Would you see the text?

Comment: @Lord Shark the Unknown would you just write an answer with full definitions instead of comments so I understand better what you are saying about cokernel.

Comment: Please read prop 12.12 carefully. The rows in the double complex are the sequences in that proposition **except** that the $\Omega_c^*(M)$ terms are omitted. This means the cohomology of these rows are precisely the $\Omega_c^*(M)$ concentrated in dimension zero.

Comment: I read it carefully, I simply do not understand the notion of omit and  concentrate. Cohomology in this book is defined as ker/image, kernel of the forward map and image of the previous one. So at position zero or any other position, there should be a map going in and one coming out. In position zero the map going out is sum and the map going in is delta and by exactness the cohomology is zero at position zero. If we drop the forms on $M$ and hence the sum map then I know of no way of defining cohomology for $\Omega_c^*(U_{\alpha_0})$ forms.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80833/discussion-between-alireza-and-lord-shark-the-unknown).